# Html.TextAreaFor() Remove default styling

Tags: html, css, razor

I´m using some HTML helper for a registration form, but some of them have a outline which is not incluyed in my CSS.

I tried removing paramaters which I belive could be related.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.correo, new { @type = "email", @placeholder = "Correo", @class = "input_helper" })
```

```
.form_box .input_helper {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 15px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 24px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    color: white;
}
```

Here´s how it looks

[image: Page Preview]

Comment: That's the resizing handle for your textarea elements. Given what you're showing here, is there a reason you're not using input elements?

Comment: I´m working with MVC Razor and I need those values for a Model.

Comment: `@Html.TextAreaFor()` generates `<textarea></textarea>` elements. Unless you need multiline text entry, `@Html.TextBoxFor()` would seem like a better match for what you've shown, since that generates `<input type="text" />` elements. Otherwise, you need to add `resize: none` to the CSS for your textareas (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize).

Answer (score 0):

Removed the resizing handle. ([Tieson T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534109/tieson-t))

```
 .input_helper {
    resize:none;
}
```